# How to check which scheduled program runs every day in windows 7?

Tags: mysql, windows, scheduled-tasks

I have windows 7 and recently also MySQL server on my desktop.

There was a program running every day at 00:00, a black window with green text was visible and I thought (sorry, already forgotten) it was something with MySQL notifier, and it was reading my cd-rom ...

I removed this setting (but I can't find it anymore, maybe it was a mysql stored procedure) and since than the program is not running anymore.

BUT I discovered that still some program is running every day at 00:00 and checks my cd-rom (I hear that every day exactly at 00:00, so it was not that other program but at the same time). So I want to know which program so I am sure that nobody reads also my usb sticks etc. every day (you can't see it, but a cd-rom you hear).

How can I check this in windows 7 professional (maybe in a log etc.) ?

Comment: this is a site for programming questions. Stay off other questionable sites, wink wink, and get an anti-virus program

Comment: Sorry I did not know, shall not happen again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on `Start` in the search bar type `scheduler` and click on the listed program. That will bring up windows task scheduler.
In the `Active Tasks` Section you can see all the task that are scheduled to run

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rahul, that was simple. A system restore scheduled task (named SR in Win7) controls when a snapshot occurs. By default, the task is set to run at 12:00AM every day. I go to read what this exactly means, never experienced in another windows version.